# Indent only the first line of a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I'd like to indent the first line of a uitextview, but haven't find a way to do this. I'd think it would be possible since it's a pretty common paragraph behavior..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it will insert 4 spaces at the beginning of the first line of the textView (not at the first line of each paragraph, I'm not sure which you wanted?)

```
textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,0) withString:@"    "];
```

To Prevent the user from moving the selection point to the indent:

Set the textview's delegate and implement the [`textViewDidChangeSelection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChangeSelection%3a) method

Then in the method, do something like:

```
if (textView.selectedRange.location < 4) {
    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(4, 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. This led me to something that's close.. I've combined it with shouldChangeTextInRange to keep the range from being edited. The only issue still remaining (and that I don't see a solution for) is that the user can still place their cursor inside of or at the beginning of that range. I'll post my code soon.

Comment: @Alan, I have edited my answer to include how to prevent the user placing the cursor in the indent.